# HTML, CSS | Page Blurs on resize

Tags: html, css, google-maps, resize

### ISSUE

I have created a login page for my new system and the background uses google maps which is interactive and you can click and move the map about (see image below). The issue i am having is when the page is full screen everything looks fine but whenever you resize the page the content starts too blur. This is the first time i have had this so i presume its the google maps.

Full Screen - no blur
[image]

Resized - blurred and hard to read text at some sizes
[image]

Although it may be hard to tell here the login box in the center is blurred in the resized to half screen version. the only things which blurr are the things the map is behind.

Any Idea?

Thanks in advance, Kieran

Comment: I think you should try if reloading the page fix the blurry issue. If so, you should trigger the google maps resize function (when the size of your window changed)

Comment: Refreshhing the page does nothing, although it is confirmed it is the maps now because it only blurrs once the map has loaded